# Simplifying an ellipse by change of bases

Tags: linear-algebra

ellipse = $2x^2 - 4xy + 5y^2 = 1$

I found the transition matrix, P, for the given bases:

B' = {(2/$\sqrt5$, 1/$\sqrt5$),(-1/$\sqrt5$, 2/$\sqrt5$)
B = {(1,0), (0,1)}

P = $\begin{bmatrix} 
2/\sqrt5 & 
-1/\sqrt5 
\\ 
1/\sqrt5  & 
2/\sqrt5 
\end{bmatrix}$

2) Convert a coordinate matrix $\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}$ relative to the basis $B'$ into the coordinate matrix $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ relative to the basis $B$. Plug both $x,y$ found in 2) to the original equation and find a simplified equation in terms of the variables $x', y'$

Here is where I am confused by what the question is asking. I chose values for x' and y'. $\begin{bmatrix}x'=1\\y'=1\end{bmatrix}$ and then plug it in and get x, y values.

$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix} 
2/\sqrt5 & 
-1/\sqrt5 
\\ 
1/\sqrt5  & 
2/\sqrt5 
\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix} 
\sqrt2
\\ 
\sqrt1.8
\end{bmatrix}$

Here is where I am stuck. How am i supposed to plug the x and y values into the eclipse equation to make it a "simplified" equation?

Comment: Small suggestion: the thing you're simplifying is an **ellipse**; an *eclipse* is an occultation of one celestial body by another.

Comment: thank you.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 
2/\sqrt5 & 
-1/\sqrt5 
\\ 
1/\sqrt5  & 
2/\sqrt5 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}$$
(or the reverse), and mutliplying out, you get something that looks like
$$
x = ax' + b y'\\
y = c x' + d y'
$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are things involving $\sqrt{5}$ and other stuff.

You are now supposed to substitute those into the terms of 
$$
2x^2 - 4xy + 5y^2 = 1
$$
to get something like 
$$
2(ax' + by')^2 - 4\ldots = 1
$$
which you expand out to get a quadratic expression in $x'$ and $y'$ rather than in $x$ and $y$.

I'm not going to do the work for you, but at least you now know what you're being asked to do. The idea was to do this stuff for a *general* $x',y'$ pair, not a particular numerical pair.